# Save a image from asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, save-image

,Hope i get this clear.

I have a asp.net  website, as part of it i generate a bitmap and need to save it some were so i can display it later on.

for now my sites is locate here:

```
http://tools.myDomain.com/mySite/
```

I have created a directory with in my site:

```
http://tools.myDomain.com/mySite/img/
```

Now i am trying to save my bitmap to there like this:

```
bitmap.Save(@"http://tools.myDomain.com/mySite/img/bitmap.png");
```

I can get this to work, not from my computer locally and not when i do Publish to my site...

Any ideas how can i fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save it on the server not on the web

`bitmap.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/img/bitmap.png"));`

Comment: think it will be great, now can you please tell me how i read that img using javascript?

Comment: try to debug find out what HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath returns the folder has exsist before it will work i hope it helps

Comment: My mistake, locally it worked fine, but when i do Publish to my site it doesnt save the image.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("/mySite/img/bitmap.png"));
```

Or you can use an absolute path

```
bitmap.Save("c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mySite\img\bitmap.png");
```

Note that the path is just an example and should be your absolute path.

Comment: thanks, it doesnt work when i publish me site, what could be the problem? any idea?

Comment: What are the Read/Write/permissions on the mySite/img folder? If they do not have the correct permissions set up then you would not be able to save the image

Comment: It has Write/permissions, what else does it need?

Comment: write permission for what user? It would require permissions for `NETWORK SERVICE`

Comment: I added the user, but still didnt work, is there any other user i should be adding?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permissions for ASPNET user. It will work for sure.

Comment: Thank you, but when i try to add that user, i tells me it cant be found.

Comment: do one thing add following tag in web.config

<identity impersonate="true" />